# How to create category with inner join?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to create a category with inner join?

---

Code

```
<?php
                $sorgu = mysql_query("select Sr.soru,Sc.secenek from tibbianamnezsorulari Sr inner join tibbianamnezsecenekleri Sc on Sc.soruID = Sr.soruID");
                while($calistir = mysql_fetch_array($sorgu))
                {   
                    ?>
            <tr>
              <th width="593" style="text-align:left;"><?php echo $calistir["soru"];?></th>
              <th>&nbsp;</th>
              <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align:left;"><?php echo $calistir["secenek"]; ?></td>
              <td align="center" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
```

---

output

```
Aşağıdaki yakınmalardan herhangi birini yaşadınız mı?        
Balgamlı Öksürük         
Aşağıdaki yakınmalardan herhangi birini yaşadınız mı?        
Nefes Darlığı        
Aşağıdaki yakınmalardan herhangi birini yaşadınız mı?        
Göğüs Ağrısı         
Aşağıdaki yakınmalardan herhangi birini yaşadınız mı?        
Çarpıntı         
Aşağıdaki yakınmalardan herhangi birini yaşadınız mı?        
Sırt Ağrısı          
Aşağıdaki yakınmalardan herhangi birini yaşadınız mı?        
İshal veya Kabızlık          
Aşağıdaki yakınmalardan herhangi birini yaşadınız mı?        
Eklemlerde Ağrı
```

---

I want

```
Aşağıdaki yakınmalardan herhangi birini yaşadınız mı?

    Balgamlı Öksürük
    Nefes Darlığı
    Göğüs Ağrısı       
    Çarpıntı       
    Sırt Ağrısı
    İshal veya Kabızlık       
    Eklemlerde Ağrı
```

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_*`, they are [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php). Use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [mysqli](http://us2.php.net/mysqli) instead.

Comment: post your table schema  and relations or dependencies ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This Code

```
<?php
      $sorgu = mysql_query("select Sr.soru,Sc.secenek from tibbianamnezsorulari Sr inner join tibbianamnezsecenekleri Sc on Sc.soruID = Sr.soruID");
      $prv_value = '';
      while ($calistir = mysql_fetch_array($sorgu)) {   
         if ($prv_value != $calistir["soru"]) {
 ?>
 <tr>
     <th width="593" style="text-align:left;"><?php echo $calistir["soru"];?></th>
     <th>&nbsp;</th>
     <th>&nbsp;</th>
 </tr>
 <?php 
          }//end if condition
 ?>
  <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left;"><?php echo $calistir["secenek"]; ?></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <?php
           $prv_value = $calistir["soru"];                
         }//end while loop
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
    $sorgu = mysql_query("select Sr.soru,Sc.secenek from tibbianamnezsorulari Sr inner join tibbianamnezsecenekleri Sc on Sc.soruID = Sr.soruID");
    $check = true;
    while($calistir = mysql_fetch_array($sorgu))
    {
       if($check){ ?>
        <tr>
            <th width="593" style="text-align:left;"><?php echo $calistir["soru"];?></th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
           <?php $check = false;} ?>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:left;"><?php echo $calistir["secenek"]; ?></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response

output

Aşağıdaki yakınmalardan herhangi birini yaşadınız mı?
Balgamlı Öksürük
Nefes Darlığı
Göğüs Ağrısı
Çarpıntı
Sırt Ağrısı
İshal veya Kabızlık
Eklemlerde Ağrı
Kalp hastalığı
Şeker hastalığı
Böbrek rahatsızlığı
Sarılık
Mide veya on iki parmak ülseri
İşitme kaybı
Görme bozukluğu
Sinir sistemi hastalığı
Deri hastalığı
Besin zehirlenmesi

Answer (score -1):

This might not be very efficient, but I would do it this way:

```
<?php 

// select category column first.
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT category_column FROM table_1 AS T1 INNER JOIN table_2 AS T2 ON T1.id = T2.id");

while ($result1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
    // print out category.
    echo $category = $result1["category_column"];
    // select item column then.
    $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT category_column, item_column FROM table_1 AS T1 INNER JOIN table_2 AS T2 ON T1.id = T2.id");
    while ($result2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
        if ($result2['category_column'] == $category) {
            echo $item = $result2["item_column"];
        }
    }
}

 ?>
```